# Not able to run java servelet

Tags: java, tomcat

Iam an absolute beginer to java web programing and servelts. Iam trying to see the output of my helloworld servelt using tomcat but i cant get the luck.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class helloworld extends HttpServlet {

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

i compiled the above code and placed the helloworld.class file in

webapps/myApp/WEB-INF/classes/helloworld.class

stoped and started the tomcat and hit the url than i got 404.

http://localhost:8080/myApp/servlet/helloworld

i got no idea whats wrong here .

Comment: Why do you think that sending a request to /servlet/TestingServlet should invoke your helloworld servlet? Suppose you add a second servlet, which one would the container invoke then? Shouldn't there be some setting somewhere telling the container which servlet to invoke on which paths? What does your tutorial say about that?

Comment: sorry its helloworld only , i just tried with web.xml with descriptor testingservelt but no luck

Comment: You tried **what**?

Comment: you need your servlet get mapped to a url in the web.xml    which IDE do you use (Netbeans, Eclipse, ..)? usually these tools can help with the mapping. edit your question and add the web.xml too

Comment: I'm just using notepad

Comment: bro what you have kept in WEB-INF ?? from where did you started learning?  read something about web.xml

Comment: Please go through with this tutorial it may help you.


https://www.javatpoint.com/steps-to-create-a-servlet-using-tomcat-server

Comment: @khAn yep i got it. can you please help me with the URL without web.xml

Comment: @saikrishna without web.xml you can't run servlet application. there nothing wrong in URL the thing is we have to configure web.xml according to your XML.

Comment: For testing purposes, Tomcat used to support a mechanism where you could invoke a servlet directly by its class name: ``http://host:port/servlet/com.acme.myservlet``. I don't know if that still works.